# How to manage partial matching with regex?

Tags: regex, scala

I have  a regex  like this:

```
val myregex = "This is a (.*) text for (.*) and other thing like .*".r
```

If I run :

```
> val myregex(a,b) = "This is a test text for something and other thing like blah blah"
a: String = test
b: String = something
```

it is ok, and it fails is `b` is missing:

```
> val myregex(a,b) = "This is a test text for and other thing like blah blah"
scala.MatchError: This is a test text for and other thing like blah blah (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 33 elided
```

Is there a way to keep for example the value `a` and replace `b` with a fallback value (and viceversa)? Or the only solution is splitting the regex in two distincts regexs?

Answer (score 2):

Your original regex requires 2 consecutive spaces between `for` and `and`.

You may change your regex to actually match the string with an optional pattern by wrapping the space and the subsequent `(.*)` pattern with a *non-capturing group* and apply the `?` quantifier to it making it *optional*:

```
val myregex = "This is a (.*) text for(?: (.*))? and other thing like .*".r
val x = "This is a test text for and other thing like blah blah"
x match {
    case myregex(a, b) => print(s"${a} -- ${b}");
    case _ => print("none")
}
// => test -- null
```

See the [online Scala demo](https://ideone.com/QZEQJd). Here, there is a match, but `b` is just null since the second *capturing* group did not participate in the match (and did not get initialized).

Answer (score 0):

> Or the only solution is splitting the regex in two distincts regexs?

This is the only solution. Your best bet is probably to use pattern matching:

```
("This is a test text for something", "and other thing like blah blah") match {
  case (r1(a), r2(b)) => (a, b)
  case (r1(a), _)     => (a, "fallback")
}
```

Comment: In rare situation there is "the only solution".